# подпись в Outlook выводит имя домена

Tags: powershell, active-directory, outlook

При добавление подписи в Outlook по этому скрипту
в поле сайт выводит `www.site.ru`, а гиперссылка с указанием домена `name/www.site.ru`.

```
#Custom variables
$CompanyName = ‘name'
$SigSource = "\\dc-server.name.local\scripts$\$CompanyName"
$ForceSignatureNew = '1' #When the signature are forced the signature are enforced as default signature for new messages the next time the script runs. 0 = no force, 1 = force
$ForceSignatureReplyForward = '1' #When the signature are forced the signature are enforced as default signature for reply/forward messages the next time the script runs. 0 = no force, 1 = force

#Environment variables
$AppData=(Get-Item env:appdata).value
$SigPath = ‘\Microsoft\Signatures'
$LocalSignaturePath = $AppData+$SigPath
$LocalSignatureFile = $LocalSignaturePath+'\'+$CompanyName+' официальная.files'
$RemoteSignaturePathFull = $SigSource+'\'+$CompanyName+'.docx'

#Get Active Directory information for current user
$UserName = $env:username
$Filter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$UserName))"
$Searcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher
$Searcher.Filter = $Filter
$ADUserPath = $Searcher.FindOne()
$ADUser = $ADUserPath.GetDirectoryEntry()
$ADDisplayName = $ADUser.DisplayName
$ADEmailAddress = $ADUser.mail
$ADTitle = $ADUser.title
$ADTelePhoneNumber = $ADUser.TelephoneNumber
$ADMobileNumber = $ADUser.Mobile
$ADStreetAddress = $ADUser.StreetAddress
$ADwWWHomePage = $ADUser.wWWHomePage

#Setting registry information for the current user
$CompanyRegPath = "HKCU:\Software\"+$CompanyName

if (Test-Path $CompanyRegPath)
{}
else
{New-Item -path "HKCU:\Software" -name $CompanyName}

if (Test-Path $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings')
{}
else
{New-Item -path $CompanyRegPath -name "Outlook Signature Settings"}

$SigVersion = (gci $RemoteSignaturePathFull).LastWriteTime #When was the last time the signature was written
$ForcedSignatureNew = (Get-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings').ForcedSignatureNew
$ForcedSignatureReplyForward = (Get-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings').ForcedSignatureReplyForward
$SignatureVersion = (Get-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings').SignatureVersion
Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name SignatureSourceFiles -Value $SigSource
#присваиваем переменные взяв значения из реестра
$TelephoneNumberREG = (Get-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings').TelephoneNumber
$DisplayNameREG = (Get-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings').DisplayName
$EmailAddressREG = (Get-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings').EmailAddress
$TitleREG = (Get-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings').ADTitle
$MobileNumberREG= (Get-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings').ADMobileNumber
$StreetAddressREG=(Get-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings').ADStreetAddress
$wWWHomePageREG=(Get-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings').wWWHomePage

$SignatureSourceFiles = (Get-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings').SignatureSourceFiles


#Forcing signature for new messages if enabled
if ($ForcedSignatureNew -eq '1')
{
#Set company signature as default for New messages
$MSWord = New-Object -com word.application
$EmailOptions = $MSWord.EmailOptions
$EmailSignature = $EmailOptions.EmailSignature
$EmailSignatureEntries = $EmailSignature.EmailSignatureEntries
$EmailSignature.NewMessageSignature=$CompanyName
$MSWord.Quit()
}

#Forcing signature for reply/forward messages if enabled
if ($ForcedSignatureReplyForward -eq '1')
{
#Set company signature as default for Reply/Forward messages
$MSWord = New-Object -com word.application
$EmailOptions = $MSWord.EmailOptions
$EmailSignature = $EmailOptions.EmailSignature
$EmailSignatureEntries = $EmailSignature.EmailSignatureEntries
$EmailSignature.ReplyMessageSignature=$CompanyName
$MSWord.Quit()
}

#Copying signature sourcefiles and creating signature if signature-version are different from local version
$FileExists =  Test-Path "$LocalSignatureFile"
if ($SignatureVersion -eq $SigVersion -And $StreetAddressREG -eq $ADStreetAddress -and $wWWHomePageREG -eq $ADwWWHomePage -And $MobileNumberREG -eq $ADMobileNumber -And $TelephoneNumberREG -eq $ADTelePhoneNumber -And $DisplayNameREG -eq $ADDisplayName -And $EmailAddressREG -eq $ADEmailAddress -And $ADTitleREG -eq $ADTitle -and $FileExists -eq $true) 
{}
else
{

#Copy signature templates from domain to local Signature-folder
#Copy-Item "$SignatureSourceFiles\* $LocalSignaturePath -Force -Recurse
Copy-Item $SignatureSourceFiles $LocalSignaturePath -Force -Recurse

$ReplaceAll = 2
$FindContinue = 1
$MatchCase = $False
$MatchWholeWord = $True
$MatchWildcards = $False
$MatchSoundsLike = $False
$MatchAllWordForms = $False
$Forward = $True
$Wrap = $FindContinue
$Format = $False

#Insert variables from Active Directory to rtf signature-file
$MSWord = New-Object -com word.application
$fullPath = $LocalSignaturePath+'\'+$CompanyName+'\'+$CompanyName+'.docx'
$MSWord.Documents.Open($fullPath)

#www
$FindText = "wWWHomePage"
$ReplaceText = $ADwWWHomePage.ToString()
$MSWord.Selection.Find.Execute($FindText, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord,    $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap,    $Format, $ReplaceText, $ReplaceAll    )

#Адрес
$FindText = "StreetAddress"
$ReplaceText = $ADStreetAddress.ToString()
$MSWord.Selection.Find.Execute($FindText, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord,    $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap,    $Format, $ReplaceText, $ReplaceAll    )

#Мобила
$FindText = "MobileNumber"
$ReplaceText = $ADMobileNumber.ToString()
$MSWord.Selection.Find.Execute($FindText, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord,    $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap,    $Format, $ReplaceText, $ReplaceAll    )

#Городской телефон
$FindText = "TelephoneNumber"
$ReplaceText = $ADTelephoneNumber.ToString()
$MSWord.Selection.Find.Execute($FindText, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord,    $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap,    $Format, $ReplaceText, $ReplaceAll    )

#Отображаемое Имя
$FindText = "DisplayName"
$ReplaceText = $ADDisplayName.ToString()
$MSWord.Selection.Find.Execute($FindText, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord,    $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap,    $Format, $ReplaceText, $ReplaceAll    )

#Описание\должность
$FindText = "Title"
$ReplaceText = $ADTitle.ToString()
$MSWord.Selection.Find.Execute($FindText, $MatchCase, $MatchWholeWord,    $MatchWildcards, $MatchSoundsLike, $MatchAllWordForms, $Forward, $Wrap,    $Format, $ReplaceText, $ReplaceAll    )

#Имейл
$MSWord.Selection.Find.Execute("Email")
$MSWord.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add($MSWord.Selection.Range, "mailto:"+$ADEmailAddress.ToString(), $missing, $missing, $ADEmailAddress.ToString())


$MSWord.Selection.Find.Execute($ADwWWHomePage.ToString())
$MSWord.ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add($MSWord.Selection.Range, $ADwWWHomePage.ToString())

$MSWord.ActiveDocument.Save()

$saveFormat = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat], "wdFormatHTML");
[ref]$BrowserLevel = "microsoft.office.interop.word.WdBrowserLevel" -as [type]
$MSWord.ActiveDocument.WebOptions.OrganizeInFolder = $true
$MSWord.ActiveDocument.WebOptions.UseLongFileNames = $true
$MSWord.ActiveDocument.WebOptions.BrowserLevel = $BrowserLevel::wdBrowserLevelMicrosoftInternetExplorer6
$path = $LocalSignaturePath+'\'+$CompanyName+".htm"

$MSWord.ActiveDocument.saveas([ref]$path, [ref]$saveFormat)
$saveFormat = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat], "wdFormatRTF");
$path = $LocalSignaturePath+'\'+$CompanyName+" официальная.rtf"

$MSWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs([ref] $path, [ref]$saveFormat)
$saveFormat = [Enum]::Parse([Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat], "wdFormatText");
$path = $LocalSignaturePath+'\'+$CompanyName+" официальная.rtf"

$MSWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs([ref] $path, [ref]$saveFormat)
$path = $LocalSignaturePath+'\'+$CompanyName+" официальная.txt"
$MSWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs([ref] $path, [ref]$SaveFormat)    #::wdFormatText)

$MSWord.ActiveDocument.Close()
$MSWord.Quit()

}

#Stamp registry-values for Outlook Signature Settings if they doesn`t match the initial script variables. Note that these will apply after the second script run when changes are made in the "Custom variables"-section.
if ($ForcedSignatureNew -eq $ForceSignatureNew){}
else
{Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name ForcedSignatureNew -Value $ForceSignatureNew}

if ($ForcedSignatureReplyForward -eq $ForceSignatureReplyForward){}
else
{Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name ForcedSignatureReplyForward -Value $ForceSignatureReplyForward}


if ($SignatureVersion -eq $SigVersion){}
else
{Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name SignatureVersion -Value $SigVersion}

#проверить актуальность Городской телефон
if ($TelephoneNumberREG -eq $ADTelePhoneNumber){}
else
{Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name TelephoneNumber -Value $ADMobileNumber}
if ($TelephoneNumberREG -eq $ADTelePhoneNumber){}
else
{Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name TelephoneNumber -Value $ADMobileNumber}

#Проверить актуальность мобильного
if ($ADMobileNumberREG -eq $ADMobileNumber){}
else
{Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name TelephoneNumber -Value $ADMobileNumber}
if ($ADMobileNumberREG -eq $ADMobileNumber){}
else
{Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name TelephoneNumber -Value $ADMobileNumber}

#проверить актуальность ФИО
if ($DisplayNameREG -eq $ADDisplayName){}
else
{Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name DisplayName -Value $ADDisplayName}
if ($DisplayNameREG -eq $ADDisplayName){}
else
{Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name DisplayName -Value $ADDisplayName}

#проверить актуальность e-mail
if ($EmailAddressREG -eq $ADEmailAddress){}
else
{Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name EmailAddress -Value $ADEmailAddress}
if ($EmailAddressREG -eq $ADEmailAddress){}
else
{Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name EmailAddress -Value $ADEmailAddress}

#проверить актуальность должности
if ($ADTitleREG -eq $ADTitle){}
else
{Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name ADTitle -Value $ADTitle}
if ($ADTitleREG -eq $ADTitle){}
else
{Set-ItemProperty $CompanyRegPath'\Outlook Signature Settings' -name ADTitle -Value $ADTitle}
```